# jQuery weekly countdown timer

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a weekly countdown timer.

I have a popup which is set to only appear on Friday, Saturday and Sunday.

I need a jQuery timer which starts Friday at 00:00 and ends on Sunday at 24:00 and will work each week.

I found this jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/cwqxzm6o/151/

```
function plural(s, i) {
  return i + ' ' + (i > 1 ? s + 's' : s);
}

function sundayDelta(offset) {
  // offset is in hours, so convert to miliseconds
  offset = offset ? offset * 60 * 60 * 1000 : 0;
  var now = new Date(new Date().getTime() + offset);
  var days = 7 - now.getDay() || 7;
  var hours = 24 - now.getHours();
  var minutes =  now.getMinutes() - 00 ;
  var seconds =  now.getSeconds()- 00;
    if (hours < 0){
      days=days-1;
    }
    var positiveHours= -hours>0 ? 24-(-hours) : hours;
  return [plural('day', days),
          plural('hour', positiveHours),
          plural('minute', minutes), 
          plural('second', seconds)].join(' ');
}

// Save reference to the DIV
$refresh = $('#refresh');

$refresh.text('This page will refresh in ' + sundayDelta());

// Update DIV contents every second
setInterval(function() {
  $refresh.text('This page will refresh in ' + sundayDelta());
}, 1000);
```

However when I change my day to a Sunday the countdown goes to "7 days, 24 hours etc" when it should be saying "0 days, 24 hours etc"

Can someone lease put me out my misery and give me a updated fiddle which works?

Comment: You want to refresh the page when ""7 days, 24 hours etc" will came ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh the page when day is equal to 7 and hours is equal to 24 then you have to use **location.reload()** to refresh.
Just change our code as

```
       function plural(s, i) {
        return i + ' ' + (i > 1 ? s + 's' : s);
    }
    function reloadPage(){
        location.reload();
    }

    function sundayDelta(offset) {
        // offset is in hours, so convert to miliseconds
        offset = offset ? offset * 60 * 60 * 1000 : 0;
        var now = new Date(new Date().getTime() + offset);
        var days = 7 - now.getDay() || 7;
        var hours = 24 - now.getHours();
        var minutes = 60 - now.getMinutes();
        var seconds = 60 - now.getSeconds();
        if(now.getDay() == 7 && now.getHours() == 24){
            reloadPage();
        }
        return [plural('day', days),
            plural('hour', hours),
            plural('minute', minutes),
            plural('second', seconds)].join(' ');
    }

    // Save reference to the DIV
    $refresh = $('#refresh');

    $refresh.text('This page will refresh in ' + sundayDelta());

    // Update DIV contents every second
    setInterval(function() {
        $refresh.text('This page will refresh in ' + sundayDelta());
    }, 1000);
```

You can check here https://jsfiddle.net/Bibhudatta_sahoo/cwqxzm6o/153/
It will reload you page and reset you countdown.

Comment: Yeah but if you change you pc date to a Sunday, it reads "7 days etc" it should read that as it needs to count down to 24:00 on a Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure this is down to the fact that `now.getDay()` returns zero on a Sunday so you need to stick in a test for if `days` is equal to zero. At the moment your math is doing 7 - 0 so is returning 7.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwqxzm6o/154/)

Comment: Thank you for explaining and updating the fiddle. I changed my date to a Sunday and it currently says 12 hours and 28 minutes (at present time its 12:33pm here) , shouldn't it be reading 11 hours 28 minutes?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/089vkxr2/

You just need to change hours to 23 and minutes to 59 to get the offset right.

Comment: Hi @Jamie if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.